# How to read a .GPB file in C#?

Tags: qgis, c#, gps, assisted-gps, gpsbabel

I have a .GPB file, I need to extract the common GPS data from it but I don't find a clear structure that specify the contents of that file.

as a sample record from file

00000260 02 11 A9 61 E7 96 C4 95 B6 86 CA 01 9A 09 DC 01

how can i go through this file to get my data, I searched alot and found that it called "Dell Axim Navigation System (.gpb) file format".

Regards,

m.sai

Comment: SharpMap - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662655/reading-a-gpb-file-in-c